# How to properly apply recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table that contains hospital visits for patients. I am trying to flag visits in which a visits' `begin_date` overlaps the previous visits' `end_date` + 90 days. However, the caveat to this is that once a visit is flagged as an overlap visit, that visit should not be used to assess an overlap with another visit. Let me explain with an example.

Table

```
visitID     patientid    begin_date  end_date
1           23           1/12/2018   1/14/2018
2           23           1/30/2018   2/14/2018
3           23           4/20/2018   4/22/2018
4           23           5/02/2018   5/03/2018
5           23           7/23/2018   7/28/2018
```

In the example above, the patient had 5 visits. Visit 2's `begin_date` was in range of visit 1's `end_date` + 90 days, so visit 2 should be flagged. Once visit 2 is flagged, that row should not be used in the analysis for any future visits. Conceptually, it would be like removing visit 2 and beginning the analysis again.

interim stage (visit 2 is removed, and analysis begins again)

```
visitID     patientid    begin_date  end_date
1           23           1/12/2018   1/14/2018
3           23           4/20/2018   4/22/2018
4           23           5/02/2018   5/03/2018
5           23           7/23/2018   7/28/2018
```

So even though visit 3 overlaps with visit 2, since visit 2 has been removed, visit 3 will not be flagged as the previous visit (now visit 1) is more than `end_date` + 90 days away from visit 3's `begin_date`. Then, visit 4 should be flagged as it overlaps with a visit that was not flagged (visit 3). So since visit 4 is flagged, then visit 5 will be removed as it's `begin_date` is in the range of visit 3's `end_date` + 90 days.

Anticipated output

```
visitID     patientid    begin_date  end_date    flag
1           23           1/12/2018   1/14/2018   0
2           23           1/30/2018   2/14/2018   1
3           23           4/20/2018   4/22/2018   0
4           23           5/02/2018   5/03/2018   1
5           23           7/23/2018   7/28/2018   1
```

[@gordonlinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929329/how-to-identify-rows-that-occur-within-a-specific-time-frame), but I am running into issues using recursive CTEs. The difference between the questions is that this question needs to reference another column (`end_date`), rather than a single date column. Recursive CTEs are still a new concept to me, but I hope this will help solidify the concept.

My attempt to solve this puzzle (piggy backing off of [@gordonlinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)):

```
with vt as (
          select vt.*, row_number() over (partition by patientid order by begin_date) as seqnum
          from visits_table vt
         ),
         cte as (
          select vt.visit, vt.patientid, vt.begin_date, vt.end_date, vt.begin_date as first_begin_date, seqnum
          from vt
          where seqnum = 1
          union all
          select vt.visit, vt.patientid, vt.begin_date, vt.end_date,
                 (case when vt.begin_date > dateadd(day, 90, cte.end_date) then vt.begin_date else cte.end_date end),
                 vt.seqnum
          from cte join
               vt
               on vt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1 and vt.patientid = cte.patientid
         )
    select cte.visit, cte.patientid, cte.begin_date, cte.end_date,
           (case when first_begin_date = begin_date then 0 else 1 end) as flag
    from cte
    order by cte.patientid, cte.begin_date;
```

My edits are improperly referencing the end_date based on the results. However, I cannot find where the comparison between `begin_date` and `end_date` should be.

Dataset:

```
create table visits_table (visit int,patientid int,begin_date date, end_date date);

INSERT INTO visits_table (visit, patientid, begin_date, end_date) VALUES (1,23,'1/12/2018','1/14/2018')
INSERT INTO visits_table (visit, patientid, begin_date, end_date) VALUES (2,23,'1/30/2018','2/14/2018')
INSERT INTO visits_table (visit, patientid, begin_date, end_date) VALUES (3,23,'4/20/2018','4/22/2018')
INSERT INTO visits_table (visit, patientid, begin_date, end_date) VALUES (4,23,'5/02/2018','5/03/2018')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your sample data to make visit 5 in the range of visit 3's end_date + 90 days. Visit 3 end date is `2018-04-22`. If we add 90 days to it, it will be `2018-07-21`. Your sample data in the question has visit 5 start date as `2018-07-23`, which doesn't overlap with `2018-07-21`. So, I adjusted this to be `2018-07-20` to make these dates overlap.

```
create table visits_table (visit int,patientid int,begin_date date, end_date date);

INSERT INTO visits_table (visit, patientid, begin_date, end_date) VALUES 
(1,23,'2018-01-12','2018-01-14'),
(2,23,'2018-01-30','2018-02-14'),
(3,23,'2018-04-20','2018-04-22'),
(4,23,'2018-05-02','2018-05-03'),
(5,23,'2018-07-20','2018-07-28');
```

You query was pretty close, you just had to calculate both start and end dates of the "previous" interval `(first_begin_date, first_end_date)`.

If the "current" interval overlaps with the "previous", you carry over the "previous" interval into the current row.

Uncomment the lines in the query below to see all intermediate values.

```
with
vt
as
(
    select vt.*, row_number() over (partition by patientid order by begin_date) as seqnum
    from visits_table vt
)
,cte
as
(
    select
        vt.visit
        ,vt.patientid
        ,vt.begin_date as first_begin_date
        ,vt.end_date as first_end_date
        ,vt.begin_date
        ,vt.end_date
        ,seqnum
    from vt
    where seqnum = 1

    union all

    select
        vt.visit
        ,vt.patientid
        ,case when vt.begin_date <= dateadd(day, 90, cte.first_end_date)
            then cte.first_begin_date -- they overlap, keep the previous interval
            else vt.begin_date
        end as first_begin_date
        ,case when vt.begin_date <= dateadd(day, 90, cte.first_end_date)
            then cte.first_end_date -- they overlap, keep the previous interval
            else vt.end_date
        end as first_end_date
        ,vt.begin_date
        ,vt.end_date
        ,vt.seqnum
    from
        cte
        inner join vt
            on  vt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
            and vt.patientid = cte.patientid
)
select
    cte.visit
    ,cte.patientid
    ,cte.begin_date
    ,cte.end_date
    ,case when first_begin_date = begin_date 
        then 0 else 1
    end as flag
--  ,DATEADD(day, 90, cte.end_date) AS enddd
--  ,*
from cte
order by cte.patientid, cte.begin_date;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| visit | patientid | begin_date |  end_date  | flag |
+-------+-----------+------------+------------+------+
|     1 |        23 | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-14 |    0 |
|     2 |        23 | 2018-01-30 | 2018-02-14 |    1 |
|     3 |        23 | 2018-04-20 | 2018-04-22 |    0 |
|     4 |        23 | 2018-05-02 | 2018-05-03 |    1 |
|     5 |        23 | 2018-07-20 | 2018-07-28 |    1 |
+-------+-----------+------------+------------+------+
```